# Passing Data to other screens in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I figured out how to pass data from one screen to another in react native using navigation.navigate(screenName, {variables I want to pass along}) in the first screen and
const {variables I want to pass along} = route.params on another screen.

However, what if I want to pass that same variable from screen two to screen three? I tried doing the same thing I did from screen one to screen two, but I got and "object is undefined error for the "variables I want to pass along". Is this the wrong method for passing variables? Please let me know.

Comment: Would you please add your code here? Though your approach is acceptable, if you are using the same variable along several screens, I would suggest you to use some global state management library like `Context`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have `id` = 5, I want pass it from ScreenA to ScreenB, and ScreenB to ScreenC and below(maybe) is simplest example with [useRoute](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route/):

```
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native"
```

`ScreenA`

```
function ScreenA({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to ScreenB"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ScreenB", { id: 5 })}
    />
  );
}
```

`ScreenB`

```
function ScreenB({ navigation }) {
  const route = useRoute()
  const id = route.params?.id
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to ScreenC"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ScreenC", { id })}
    />
  );
}
```

`ScreenC`

```
function ScreenC({ navigation }) {
  const route = useRoute()
  const id = route.params?.id
  return (
    <Text>{id}</Text>
  );
}
```

`id` in ScreenC is the id you need.