# Passing parameters to a previous screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have 2 Screens im trying to pass parameters between. HomeScreen is the previous screen in this case.

```
function HomeScreen(props: {
  //some props
  route:any, 
  navigation:any,
}) {
   React.useEffect(() => {
     if (props.route.params?.defined) {
       console.log(props.route.params?.defined);
     }
   }, ); //rest of the code
```

Second component

```
function SavedRoutesScreen(props: { navigation: any }) {
  function handleGo() {
   props.navigation.navigate({
     name: "Home",
     params: { defined: true },
   });
  } //rest of the code
```

Basically im trying to pass parameters from SavedRoutesScreen to HomeScreen but I get this error. : "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route.params')"
anyone know whats up with this?

Comment: Maybe give a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188240/passing-data-to-other-screens-in-react-native

Comment: I think you need to use `.getParam` https://www.javatpoint.com/react-native-passing-value-between-screen

Comment: You should have a look on https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext, this is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two arguments to the navigation.navigate() method. I have seen that you are passing an object which is not correct.

navigation.navigate(name, params)

name - A destination name of the route that has been defined somewhere

params - Params to pass to the destination route.

Try this:

```
 props.navigation.navigate("Home", { defined: true });
```